# Shadow Glitch on Mesh Stitches

Tags: unity

I use LWRP, one Directional Light and Hard Shadows with 1024 resolution. When I imported this super simple mesh from blender this happened:

[image]

What is this weird line on the stitch of the mesh and how do I fix it? I tried using Soft Shadows with higher quality but it did not help.

Comment: Try tweaking `Normal Bias` in your Light Settings. That may give you a better result.

Comment: IIRC this bug has been known for a while. Playing with normals helps sometimes, but not always. I've seen people add another, invisible face to make the shadows work properly.

Comment: Can you make the shadows softer? By which I mean, the edges of the shadows less pixelated. It looks like if you blend them a little, you could cover the glitch.